# What is the motivation for casting a pointer into a integer?

Tags: c, linux, pointers, type-casting

I'm doing some changes in the Linux kernel code and have noticed a pointer being cast into integer.

Check out `buf` below ([full code](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/sound/core/pcm_lib.c?v=3.14#L2308)):

```
snd_pcm_sframes_t snd_pcm_lib_read(struct snd_pcm_substream *substream, void __user *buf, snd_pcm_uframes_t size)
{
    ....
    return snd_pcm_lib_read1(substream, (unsigned long)buf, size, nonblock, snd_pcm_lib_read_transfer);
}
```

It gets covered from `void __user *buf` to `(unsigned long)buf`. Afterwards in the code `buf` is treated as a `long` and not as a pointer.

Even though on the technical levels they are both numbers in memory, so far  I've perceived conceptually as different things. Is there a low level pattern on when this is used?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A typical use case (in hosted user-code applications) to cast some pointer to an `intptr_t` (from `<stdint.h>` standard C99 or C11 header) is to compute some hash code on that pointer:

```
uint32_t hash_of_foo_ptr(struct foo_st *foo) {
   return (uint32_t)(((intptr_t)foo) * 613) ^ ((intptr_t)foo % 51043));
}
```

For historical reasons (i.e. Linux came before C99), the Linux kernel uses `unsigned long` instead of `uintptr_t` (the unsigned integral type of the same `sizeof` as pointers) or `intptr_t`

Also, user-space to kernel-space transmissions (e.g. arguments of syscalls) is in the Linux kernel in terms of `long` or `unsigned long` (again, you'll better think in term of `intptr_t` or `uintptr_t`). Even when you transmit addresses from user-space to kernel-space, you need to think about address spaces and virtual memory (and it is becoming complex, since user-space and kernel-code live in different address spaces).

A quote on the topic from [LDD3](https://lwn.net/images/pdf/LDD3/ch11.pdf):

> Although, conceptually, addresses are pointers, memory administration
>   is often better accomplished by using an unsigned integer type; the
>   kernel treats physical memory like a huge array, and a memory address
>   is just an indexinto the array. Furthermore, a pointer is easily
>   dereferenced; when dealing directly with memory addresses, you
>   almost never want to dereference them in this manner. Using an integer
>   type prevents this dereferencing, thus avoiding bugs. Therefore,
>   generic memory addresses in the kernel are usually unsigned long ,
>   exploiting the fact that pointers and long integers are always the
>   same size, at least on all the platforms currently supported by Linux.

Note that the Linux kernel is not coded in hosted academically standard portable C99. It is a freestanding program, coded with a few *particular* C compilers in mind ([GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) and perhaps also *in the future* [Clang/LLVM](http://clang.llvm.org/)...).

The Linux kernel is using some [GCC extensions](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/C-Extensions.html) to C (e.g. `__attribute__`-s, builtins, computed goto-s, etc...), perhaps wrapped with macros. Most of these extensions are also supported by [Clang / LLVM](http://clang.llvm.org/).

[Kernel newbies](http://kernelnewbies.org/) & [lkml](https://lkml.org/) are probably good places to ask about that.

Comment: `user-space to kernel-space transmissions (e.g. arguments of syscalls) is in the Linux kernel in terms of long or unsigned long` is this also historical thing? Pointer as a type is available in the kernel, still can't understand the benefit.

Comment: Not at all: address in user-space and in kernel-space are different, and it is a complex issue.

Comment: And `void __user` is a keyword for a user space pointer being passed to the kernel?

Comment: It is probably some macro defined to be some `__attribute__`. AFAIK, `__user` is not a GCC *keyword*